# kong-pongo shared memory cache

Tags: testing, caching, lua, kong

I've been working on plugin tests in `kong-pongo` enviroment. In my plugin I have a memory cache. There is a possibility to set memory cache inside test case ? Get cache in the plugin

```lua
local function _find_cache(key)
  local cached, error = ngx.shared.test_cache:get(key)
  if cached then
    return cached,nil
  else
    return nil,error
  end
end

function _M:access(conf)
  --ngx.shared.test_cache:set('test', 'response', tonumber(1000)-10)
  klog.notice('----------------notice-------------')
  local cached_value = _find_cache('test')
  klog.notice('cached_value ' .. cached_value)
end
```

unit test where i'm trying to set memory cache inside test case, with configuration to start Kong test environment

```
  lazy_setup(function()
        local bp = helpers.get_db_utils(strategy == "off" and "postgres" or strategy, nil, { PLUGIN_NAME })

        local route = bp.routes:insert({
          hosts = { "test.com" },
        })

        bp.plugins:insert {
          name = PLUGIN_NAME,
          route = { id = route.id },
          config = {
          },
        }

        assert(helpers.start_kong({
          database = strategy,
          nginx_conf = "spec/fixtures/custom_nginx.template",
          plugins = "bundled," .. PLUGIN_NAME,
          nginx_http_lua_shared_dict = 'test_cache 64m',
        }, nil, nil))

      end)


      it("test cache", function()
        ngx.shared.test_cache:set('test', 'response_cache', tonumber(1000)-10)
        local res, err = client:send {
          method = "GET",
          path = "/status/200",
          headers = {
            ["Host"] = "test.com",
          },
        }
        assert.res_status(200, res)
      end)
```

value in logs is nil

```
2023/06/29 10:58:51 [notice] 96#0: *150 [kong] handler.lua:23 ----------------notice-------------, client: 127.0.0.1, server: kong, request: "GET /status/200 HTTP/1.1", host: "test.com"
2023/06/29 10:58:51 [error] 96#0: *150 [kong] init.lua:354 [hello-world] /kong-plugin/kong/plugins/hello-world/handler.lua:25: attempt to concatenate local 'cached_value' (a nil value), client: 127.0.0.1, server: kong, request: "GET /status/200 HTTP/1.1", host: "test.com"
2023/06/29 10:58:51 [info] 96#0: *150 client 127.0.0.1 closed keepalive connection
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make it work this way. First of all, I would call that an integration test, not a unit test, since you are not just testing Lua code, but actually spinning up a Kong node.

Remember; your test code runs in the Busted test framework which you run from the commandline. But the plugin itself runs inside a Kong instance (which is a completely different process), hence they cannot share anything.

That said, if you want to do this, then a way is to create another plugin, just for test purposes, that exposes an API which allows you to set values in the shared memory.

Here are some of Kong's own internal test plugins that work in a similar way: https://github.com/Kong/kong/tree/master/spec/fixtures/custom_plugins/kong/plugins